# Regular expression pattern to match only links without www

Tags: php, regex, expression, html-parsing

I'm trying to search for only links without `www` like `http://google.com`, OR `https://facebook.com`, etc.  Then I want to add `www` to same link so it becomes `http://www.google.com`, OR `https://www.facebook.com`, etc.

However, I have a problem in my pattern (the pattern I used to get all links with or without www).

```
$text = '<a href="http://google.com">google</a> bla bla bla <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>';
preg_match_all("/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU", $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches[2] as $old_url) 
{
$text = str_replace("$old_url","$new_url",$text);
}
```

Comment: What's your problem in this pattern?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  (this pattern i used get all links with or without www) i search about only links without `www` to add it for same link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code with the `<a\\s[^>]*href=([\"']?)(?>https?|ftps?):\/\/(?![^'\">]*www[^\"]+?\\1)([^'\">]+?)\\1[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/a>` regex to match only those URLs in href attributes that have no `www` in them.

[Sample code](http://goo.gl/HgbdLN):

```
$re = "/<a\\s[^>]*href=([\"']?)(?>https?|ftps?):\/\/(?![^'\">]*www[^\"]+?\\1)([^'\">]+?)\\1[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/a>/"; 
$str = "<a href=\"http://google.com\">google</a> bla bla bla <a href=\"https://www.google.com\">google</a> bla bla bla <a href=\"http://facebook.com\">facebook</a>\n"; 
print ($str . "\n");
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    $re,
    function ($matches) {
        return str_replace($matches[2], "www." . $matches[2], $matches[0]);
  },
  $str
);
print ($str);
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> bla bla bla <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a> bla bla bla <a href="http://www.facebook.com">facebook</a>
```

Comment: thanx , but not work a well , if you try use `$text = '<a href="http://google.com">google</a> bla bla bla <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a> bla bla bla <a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a>';` and print `$matches[2]` you will have only 1 link but must have 2 links .

Comment: @omardealo: I agree, there was a problem with a greedy `(.*)`. I replaced it with `(.*?)`, and it works as expected.

Comment: thanx brother now is working very good , can u help me with use the result  to replace it ,  after i get links without www (i want add www in this links ) `foreach ($matches[2] as $link)
{
   $str = str_replace($link,$link_with_www, $str);
}`

Comment: @omardealo: Done, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using **DOM** and **XPath** to take care of this for you.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query('//a[not(contains(@href, "www."))]/@href');

foreach ($links as $link) {
   // process yours urls by $link->nodeValue
   ...
   ...
 }
```

You could probably then use `parse_url()` to replace while processing the url.

Comment: thanx but sorry i cannot understand ur code , can u explain it , like that's my var Content `$this->post['message']` how can i used it with ur code .

Comment: yeah i change it already , i mean used `$this->post['message']` in line `str_replace`

Comment: that's right ? `$this->post['message'] = str_replace($url['host'], 'www.' . $url['host'], $this->post['message']);`

Comment: it work but not well , if ur text have 2 of same link , like `http://google.com bla bla http://google.com` first link is okay but Second link will be like `http://www.www.google.com/` and if have three links will be add more of `www`